# Will my WLAN interface IP address ever change?

Tags: networking, ifconfig

A naive question, I'm trying to understand output from ifconfig.

```
wlp59s0 == wlan, pci bus 59, slot 0 (pci or port??)
```

The inet addr is: 192.168.1.240. Is this statically assigned to the card for its lifetime or is it programmable?

Comment: Strange.  Could you post the command and the full result of `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 0):

IP is never `assigned to the card for its lifetime` it can be specified statically in the network config or it can be assigned by DHCP server.

To answer your question - yes, it can be changed. And the other question - will it ever change - it could but does not have to. You can get the same IP from DHCP server every time (but does not have to as DHCP can be set to provide the same IP every time)

Maybe if you provide more context why you ask this you could get more specific answer.